# OpenSSL's EC_POINT_mul taking a LOT of memory

Tags: c, openssl

First off, I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 and a pre-built 64-bit version of OpenSSL.  I need to do a significant number of EC multiplications on the secp256k1 curve, and I found while running my program that the memory usage just kept going up and up.  So I used heap profiling to narrow it down, and the VAST majority of things that don't get freed from the heap come from the EC_POINT_mul function.  Here is my function for getting a public key from a private key and a test for 10,000 iterations of it:

```
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void getPubKey(uint8_t privKey[], uint8_t* out[])
{
    EC_KEY* pkey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(714); //set to secp256k1
    const EC_GROUP *pgroup = EC_KEY_get0_group(pkey);
    EC_POINT *pub_key = EC_POINT_new(pgroup);

    BIGNUM* privKeyBN = BN_bin2bn(privKey, 32, NULL);

    EC_KEY_set_private_key(pkey, privKeyBN);

    BN_CTX* ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    EC_POINT_mul(pgroup, pub_key, privKeyBN, NULL, NULL, ctx);

    char* pubUnc = EC_POINT_point2hex(pgroup, pub_key, 6, ctx);

    HexToBin(pubUnc, out, 65);

    EC_POINT_free(pub_key);
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    BN_free(privKeyBN);
    EC_KEY_free(pkey);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        uint8_t* finalPrivKey = malloc(32);
        memset(finalPrivKey, 156, 32);
        uint8_t* finalFullPubKey = malloc(65);
        memset(finalFullPubKey, 0, 65);
        getPubKey(finalPrivKey, finalFullPubKey);
        free(finalPrivKey);
        free(finalFullPubKey);
    }
}
```

According to the heap profiling, the first time I run getPubKey, 17,880 bytes is added to the heap in 33 allocations when it hits EC_POINT_mul().  Then every time after that, it adds 132 bytes to the heap in 1 allocation.  All of the freeing of objects at the end doesn't fix it, so all of those 132 bytes add up.  If I have to run 10 million EC multiplications, that's 1.25GB!  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't see where you're freeing the string at `pubUnc` returned by `EC_POINT_point2hex`.  According to the man page at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EC_POINT_new.html that string must be freed by passing it to `OPENSSL_free`.

Comment: This is it- thank you!  I guess I have to RTFM better.